# Пожалуйста, оставьте ваш отзыв о Stack Overflow!

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, итоги-года

Спешу предложить участникам сообщества оставить отзыв на основе пяти вопросов о наболевшем за год (или все время):

- о работе компании;
- о том, чего не хватало в прошлом;
- о том, чего вы хотите видеть в будущем;

Пожалуйста, заполните форму: https://goo.gl/FRwmfy.  Форма анонимная, ответить на вопросы можно лишь один раз. Скорее всего, написание ответов не займет у вас более 15 минут.

Ваше мнение обязательно будет услышано! Я постараюсь сделать все возможное, чтобы все, о чем вы напишите, при необходимости и возможности, было рассмотрено, ошибки учтены, рекомендации выполнены.

Stack Overflow (компании) и мне лично крайне важно ваше мнение. Мы хотим создать лучшую *по–вашему мнению* систему накопления и многократного использования накопленных знаний. Для нас крайне важно, чтобы всем пользователям и участникам было приятно и полезно использовать сайт.

[Пройти опрос »](https://goo.gl/FRwmfy)

Сбор отзывов продлится до 10-го января 2017 года.

С нетерпением ждем ваших отзывов!

Comment: а что? там вариантов ответов нет? самому надо что-то придумывать?

Comment: @Grundy Ага! Цель опроса – услышать мнение сообщества, что вам интересно, а не рассказать варианты видения компании.

Comment: А ответы подразумеваются на русском, я надеюсь? :)

Comment: @Grundy Да, конечно! Пожелания (последний пункт) – тоже на русском.

Comment: Последний вроде про письмо Джоелю?

Comment: @Grundy Не обязательно Джоэлю. Можете мне написать, я буду рад :)

Comment: @Grundy Добавил пояснение в шапку опроса.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я бы прошел опрос но почему он к гугловой почте привязан? почему не к SO?

Comment: @perfect Это Google Forms. Они никак не связаны со Stack Overflow. На самом деле, опрос анонимный. Google Forms требует быть авторизированным лишь для того, чтобы обеспечить работу настроек опроса (например, один ответ от одного пользователя). Мы не будем видеть адресов прошедших опрос участников.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Больше писал про ru SO. Так обидно, что забыл самое главное Джоелю передать: уберите приоритет у принятого ответа при сортировке ответов. Хотя бы как опция в профиле. [Соответствующий запрос](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top) был успешно проигнорирован.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А есть такая же, только на англ. SO форма вопросов? Чтобы об этом отписать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Нет, такая форма только в нашем сообществе. Мы самые инициативные! :)

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky, будут ли учитываться ответы на анкету, в которых присутствует ненормативная лексика?

Comment: @Majestio Конечно же, ненормативную лексику лучше не употреблять.

Comment: > Чтобы заполнить форму, войдите в аккаунт Google > В этой форме есть функции, для использования которых необходимо войти в аккаунт. Ответ будет отправлен анонимно. Слоооооожно... > Google Forms требует быть авторизированным лишь для того, чтобы обеспечить работу настроек опроса (например, один ответ от одного пользователя). Что, правда у всех есть только один gmail-аккаунт?

Comment: Всем, кто принял участие в опросе огромное спасибо! В самое ближайшее время все отзывы будут проанализированы.